# Platform suggestions for android app without javascript

Tags: android

Is there any cross platform tool apart from xamarin for developing an app,which is not functioning on javascript,

Comment: try corona labs, qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this links  will helps you...

http://thinkapps.com/blog/development/develop-for-ios-v-android-cross-platform-tools/

https://www.business.com/articles/top-5-cross-platform-app-development-tools-in-2016/